# MKMapView Clicking on pins won't call didSelectAnnotationView

Tags: objective-c, mkmapview, mkannotationview, mkmapviewdelegate

I am using a mapView and am trying to make a callout pop up when you click on a pin which is shown on the map.

The pins manage to be placed in the proper locations so I think the annotations work but when I click on the pin it won't show a callout.  I have show callout = YES.

The method `didSelectAnnotationView` does not get called at all when I click on the pin.

Are there some common problems which may cause this method not to be called?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If tapping on a pin doesn't show the callout even if `canShowCallout` is `YES`, then the annotation's `title` is probably `nil` or blank.

If the `title` is blank, the callout won't show nor will the `didSelectAnnotationView` delegate method get called.

Comment: Yup turns out I wasnt setting the title of my annotation properly and hence it wasnt working, thanks

Comment: after so much search, saw ur answer, then had a look at the custom annotation object only name was a weak property by mistake and i was like blasting, thanks

Comment: this is an annoying behaviour of MKMapView - thanks for the heads up :)