# How to make a delegate, my mapview won't respond to didSelectAnnotationView

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have a mapview with custom class mapviewHandler assigned to it and it is added to blaViewController.h as `@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet mapviewHandler *mapView;`

And this is a snippet of mapviewHandler.m

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view {
    NSLog(@"test");
}
```

And this is the header file op mapviewHandler

```
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface mapviewHandler : MKMapView <MKMapViewDelegate>

@end
```

Why is it so hard to connect the mapview so it will call actions as

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView: (MKMapView *) mapView viewForAnnotation: (id<MKAnnotation>) annotation {

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView
  annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)annotationView
didChangeDragState:(MKAnnotationViewDragState)newState
    fromOldState:(MKAnnotationViewDragState)oldState
{
```

I have been struggling for days now and desperate I just want to start since this is my first time with Cocoa Touch and xcode, I'm starting to hate it already since I just can't find any good documentation and the ones I find don't explain how or it just works for them and not for me I don't know

Thx in advance please help me of my headaches and sleepless nights (yes out of this, because it is for a special assignment)

Answer (score 0):

Control drag the mapview to the view controller and link the delegates.

Alternatively create an outlet (control drag from map to .h file). Then lets say you name it map. In the .m file you would say self.map.delegate = self;  you could say this in viewDidLoad or any other loading method that you want.

Also you normally would make a UIViewController, then add the mapviewdelegate there. It seems that this is the map subclass??

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your annotation has a title.

Check this question: [MKMapView Clicking on pins won't call didSelectAnnotationView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11910824/mkmapview-clicking-on-pins-wont-call-didselectannotationview)

And don't start to hate it already, give yourself some time to learn everything :-)

Comment: I can't get '-(void)mapViewWillStartLoadingMap:(MKMapView *)mapView {' to work either, I just can't get it linked I missing a piece of information and I can't find it

Comment: When your delegate methods dont fire, its usually because your delegate is not set. If you work in IB, you have to drag the delegate to your file owner. But you can also do it in code.