# MapView MKAnnotation not showing callout on MKMapView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, mkmapview

I'm displaying a few map pins on a map view. I can't figure out why the callout won't show when an annotation is touched. Here's my code. I have some conditional code in the viewDidLoad method to display a different pin image depending on a category id. The custom pins display correctly, but when you touch them nothing happens.

thanks for any help with this.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

   [super viewDidLoad];

    [self requestData];

    CLLocationCoordinate2D centerCoord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(44.2632, 11.4403);

    MKCoordinateSpan span;
    span.latitudeDelta=5;
    span.longitudeDelta=5;

    MKCoordinateRegion ITRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(centerCoord, span);
    ITRegion.span=span;

    [mapView setRegion: ITRegion animated: YES];

    mapView.delegate=self;

    [self.mapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];


    for (int i=0; i<[publicDataArray count]; i++) {
        MKPointAnnotation* annotation= [MKPointAnnotation new];

        CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
        coordinate.latitude = [[[[publicDataArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"address"] objectForKey:@"lat"] doubleValue];
        coordinate.longitude = [[[[publicDataArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"address"] objectForKey:@"lng"] doubleValue];

        NSString *catId = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[publicDataArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"category_id"]];

        if ([catId isEqual: @"213"]) {
            annView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"comprareMap.png"];//sets image for pin

        } else if ([catId isEqual:@"217"]) {

            annView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"vedereMap.png"];//sets image for pin

        } else if ([catId isEqual:@"221"]) {

            annView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mangiareMap.png"];//sets image for pin

        }
        annotation.coordinate = coordinate;


        [mapView addAnnotation: annotation];

    }
}

- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapingView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>) annotation {
    annView = nil;
    if(annotation != mapingView.userLocation)
    {

        static NSString *defaultPinID = @"";
        annView = (MKAnnotationView *)[mapingView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:defaultPinID];
        if ( annView == nil )
            annView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc]
                       initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:defaultPinID] ;


        UIButton* rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        [rightButton setTitle:annotation.title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [rightButton addTarget:self
                        action:@selector(showDetails:)
              forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        annView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;

        annView.canShowCallout = YES;


    }
    return annView;
}
```

Comment: Make sure you set each annotation's title.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11910824/mkmapview-clicking-on-pins-wont-call-didselectannotationview.