# DidSelectAnnotationView not being called

Tags: xamarin.ios, mkmapview, xamarin

I am using Xmarin to create a map with custom annotations and for some reason the DidSelectAnnotationView method is not called once i tap on annotations.

Here is how I am creating the annotations:

```cs
public override MKAnnotationView GetViewForAnnotation (MKMapView mapView, MonoTouch.Foundation.NSObject annotation)
        {
            var item = annotation as MKPointAnnotation;
            if (item == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            if (_idToAnotations.ContainsKey (item.Title))
            {
                return _idToAnotations [item.Title];
            }
            UIView view = null;
            MKAnnotationView viewAnnotation = new MKAnnotationView ();
            Branch branch = _displayedBranches [item.Title];
            view = CreateMapAnnotation (branch.Name);   
            viewAnnotation.Add (view);
            viewAnnotation.CanShowCallout = false;                              
            return viewAnnotation;
        }
```

And here is how I am creating the view to be placed in the MKAnnotationView:

```cs
static UIView CreateMapAnnotation (string title)
        {
            UIView view = new UIView (new RectangleF (0, 0, 60, 68));
            UILabel text = new UILabel (new RectangleF (1, 0, 60, 15));
            text.Text = title;
            text.Font = text.Font.WithSize (12f);
            text.TextColor = UIColor.White;
            text.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Black;
            text.Layer.CornerRadius = 6;
            text.TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center;
            view.Add (text);
            UIImageView image = new UIImageView (new RectangleF (0, 17, 60, 40));
            image.Image = new UIImage ("map_pin_red.png");
            view.Add (image);
            return view;
        }
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: What is `_idToAnotations`?  After adding `view` to `viewAnnotation`, try setting `viewAnnotation.frame` equal to `view.frame`.  As a separate test, try commenting out the GetViewForAnnotation method completely so that the map view creates a default red pin view and see if the DidSelectAnnotationView method gets called then.

Comment: In my use case I have had definitely to set `viewAnnotation.frame = view.frame`

Answer (score 1):

I [believe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11911122/795339) that `DidSelectAnnotationView` will only be called for MKAnnotationViews that have a value for the `Title` property and `CanShowCallout` = true. If you can't make those changes, then you may need to implement a your own tap event handler.

Also is there any reason you're not using the proper constructor for MKAnnotationView with the annotation object and reuse identifier, and also calling DequeueReusableAnnotation method (see [Xamarin docs](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/platform_features/ios_maps/))? That is the best practice for most uses of annotation views.

Answer (score 0):

You have to deselect clicked annotation by calling

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didDeselectAnnotationView view: MKAnnotationView)
```

so that it will be accessible on next click.